# Redux action how to update only one objects state

Tags: redux, react-redux, state, action, reducers

I have an exercise app where a user inputs a 'name' and 'weight'. Then they are allowed to update the 'weight' of a specific 'name'. I am having trouble figuring out how to let them do this, and the closest I have gotten so far is the 'weight' of every 'name' getting updating to the exact same number. For example, if I have:

```
[
 {
  name: 'bench',
  weight: 100
 },
  name: 'squat',
  weight: 200
 },
]
```

and then the user tried to update just the weight of bench to 300, what happens is both bench and squat get updated to 300. I want just the weight of bench to get updated though.
Here is my code so far. First, my actions:

```
export const addMovement = (formValues) => {
    return {
        type: constants.ADD_MOVEMENT,
        payload: formValues,
    }
};

export const updateMovement = (formValues) => {
    return {
        type: constants.UPDATE_MOVEMENT,
        payload: formValues,
    }
};
```

My reducers:

```
const initialState = [];

const movementReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_MOVEMENT: 
            return [ ...state, action.payload ];
        case UPDATE_MOVEMENT:
            return [
                ...state.map(item => Object.assign({}, item, { movementWeight: action.payload.movementWeight }))
              ];
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

If more code is needed I will provide it, just ask. Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you find object for update by "name" field so you can try with:

```
case UPDATE_MOVEMENT:
    return [
        ...state.map(item => item.name === action.payload ? action.payload : item  )
    ];
```